# How can I test if response.location.id is defined?

Tags: javascript, variables, testing, attributes, defined

How can I test if :

```
response.location.id
```

is defined ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything? Perhaps: `if (response.location.id) {//it's defined } else { // it isn't } `

Answer (score 1):

```
if (response && response.location && typeof response.location.id !== "undefined"){

 // is defined

}
```

Comment: while hardly advisable, it is possible to do `var undefined`, which makes use of `typeof` more robust. Admittedly though, robust in the face of something rather perverse.

Comment: `typeof response.location.id !== "undefined"` surely?

Comment: @naveen agreed. There's no `undefined` keyword in javascript, so this depends upon it not being defined. It's equivalent to `!== wellWhatsTheChancesSomeOtherCodeDefinesThisNameSomewhere`

Comment: also wont `response.location.id` be falsey if undefined?

Comment: @naveen: yes, but also `0`, `null`, `false` and empty string are falsey and we'd like to know if its defined...

Comment: Though if we know that's not a valid value of id, then @naveen would have a more concise approach, hence my suggesting it **if** it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof response.location.id !== "undefined"
```

If you can't depend upon the rest being defined, then:

```
response && response.location && typeof response.location.id !== "undefined"
```

If you can depend on them, and don't have to worry about `null`, `false` or `0` as values for a defined `id`, then just test it directly (`if(response.location.id)`).